How to certbot renew without stopping webserver?
Good day,
I'm having a problem renewing a domain with certbot. This is the error I'm getting:
root@mywebserver:~# certbot renew
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mywebsite.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Renewing an existing certificate for mywebsite.com and www.mywebsite.com
Failed to renew certificate mywebsite.com with error: Could not bind TCP port 80 because it is already in use by another process on this system (such as a web server). Please stop the program in question and then try again.

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
All renewals failed. The following certificates could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebserver.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

Currently, I'm running a Wordpress instance with OpenLiteSpeed WordPress One-Click app, which is supposed to automatically renew certs for me, but it hasn't been the case.
The image comes with automatic certificate renewal by default in /etc/cron.d/certbot:
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 */12 * * * root test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew  --deploy-hook "systemctl restart lsws"
0 0 * * 3 root systemctl restart lsws

I mean, sure, I can go and stop my webserver and proceed with certbot renew process, but then I wont be able to fix this and go through all this again once the certificate ends again.
Huge thanks in advance to anyone who jumps in to help me with this.

webroom method doesn't require stopping the server: you should just tell cerbot where to put the needed files so that outside verifies can check ownership/control.


The image comes with automatic certificate renewal by default in /etc/cron.d/certbot:

That's a suboptimal image then. When you look what the certbot packages for regular linux distros install, it's typically a systemd.timer unit. Which frankly makes more sense than calling systemd in a lengthy crontab entry.
I'd just honestly copy that. See this reference answer with a link from where you can get the debian package containing that timer (should your image not contain it).
certbot renew can (and will) by itself modify your webserver configuration for verification, reload the webserver you're using, verify, revert the modification, and reload.

Debian's certbot package provides a timer entry for systemd and a crontab entry. The crontab entry exits immediately without action if systemd is present. (You can see this in the code presented in the question.)
